# How do you create a variable from a variable with %i?

Tags: python

I need `'person%s' % x` to equal what `'textvar%s' % x`, but I do not want to set `'person%s' % x` to `people[int('%s' % x)]`.

```
global people
people = ['Zach : 10', 'Danielle : 10']

global num
num = len(people)

for x in range(0, numDebt):
    globals()['textvar%s' % x] = people[int('%s' % x)]
    globals()['person%s' % x] = textvar%i % x
```

Comment: Please, [keep your data out of your variables](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html); don't produce a series of `textvar` and `person` names where a *dictionary* would do.

Comment: `x` is *already* an integer, so `int('%s' % x)` is a *very* roundabout way of just saying `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) comment, a dictionary did serve the purposes; very well in fact.